# The existence of a principal quantum level or energy shell after the loss of an electron from the outer shell of an atom

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons, atomic-structure

With the loss of an electron from $\ce{Li}$ ($\mathrm{1s^2\ 2s^1}$), we get $\ce{Li+}$ ($\mathrm{1s^2}$), then the  2nd shell where the electron had been revolving in $\ce{Li}$ will get disappeared or remain there around the nucleus but empty after the loss of the electron?

I'm actually asking for all the other atoms as well, like generally, are shells constructed already upto the very highest ones containing f orbitals in them and just remain empty when there are no electrons in them?

Comment: Chem+Math formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) // MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Well, the shell keeps existing in peoples minds, so nothing changes - it's only an abstraction.

Comment: It might be easier to think of  a ladder of energy levels which can still exist even if they  contain zero, one or two electrons